# Using operator += with multiple values

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, parameter-passing, parameter-pack

I wish to create a template of an operator +=, that would add values to the vector. I've been tinkering with the parameter packs, but it didnt work for me (i guess i did something wrong as a newbie to C++). Basically i want to achieve the effect of adding to the end of the vector with code like this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v += 3, 4, 5, 6;
```

as you can see, i want to add multiple values to the vector via operator override. This is the code i have right now:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void operator+=(std::vector<T> v1, Ts const &... ts) {

   v1.push_back(ts);

}
```

Im getting an error though, that expression contains unexpected parameter pack. If not parameter packs, then how can i add those values into the vector via overriding the operator?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unpack the va args by `v1.push_back(ts...)`.

Comment: do to `v += 3, 4, 5, 6;` is similar to do `(v += 3), 4, 5, 6;` and then `v += 3;` because the next values are unused and removed by the compiler. You are not in Python for instance, `3, 4, 5, 6` is not a tupple

Comment: Why not just use the member function that's already there? `v.insert(v.end(), {3, 4, 5, 6});`

Comment: So would that work with v+= {3,4,5,6}; for example? I was told to do specifically that, and i dont really understand why, since the best ways of doing that were with using initializer_list which would most likely solve the problem. But i dont really know if im allowed to modify this line of code ( v+= 3,4,5,6; )

Comment: You need to overload the `,` operator to get that exact syntax. It is a really odd hack that was ok to be used before initializer lists were a thing, now this looks a bit outdated

Comment: @Insekure Adding operator overloads for standard containers where no program defined type is involved usually cause more harm then good, so I hope doing this is an educational exercise. Someone seeing this in real code would immediately have to search for the operator overload to find out what it _relly_ means.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, this is an educational excercise, but thanks to you and other people helping me out in this thread i finally understand what templates and overriding operators are all about. Im very grateful. Thank you all so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overloading `+=` is not sufficient to enable that syntax literally:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v += 1,2,3,4;
```

You need a `,` too:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


struct hacky_vector {
    std::vector<int>& v;
    
    hacky_vector& operator,(int x){ 
        v.push_back(x);
        return *this;
    }
    hacky_vector& operator+=(int x){
        v.push_back(x);
        return *this;
    }
};


int main(){
    std::vector<int> x;
    hacky_vector{x} += 1,2,3,4;
    for (auto e : x) std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Without the custom `operator,` the output is just `1`, because a different way to write the above line is

```
v.operator+=(1),2,3,4;
```

The `hacky_vector` works, but is a hack that was "ok" before C++11. When there were no initializer list and no list initialization often a nicer way to initialize vector-like objects was needed and some libraries invented stuff like the above. Nowadays such hacks should not be used anymore. Use what C++ already has instead.

Initialization:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
```

Insertion (as mentioned in a comment by Ted):

```
v.insert(v.end(), {1,2,3,4,5});
```